# setting the attributes for landscape dynamically

Tags: android

Hi
how to set the attributes like width,height for landscape mode dynamically.Initially i have set the attributes for portrait in onCreate(Bundle) method.But how can i set these attributes for landscape mode.How it ll be fetched automatically when the orientation changes.
Please help me to solve this issue
`lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    55);
tr.setLayoutParams(lp);`

like this how can i set for landscape.In the landscape i want to set my width as 160 for each textview added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the below code in onCreate() .

```
        if (this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() == 0 || this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() ==2) 
        {
            // Potrait Mode
        }
        else
        {
            // Landscape Mode
        }
```

So when ever orientation change you can set your attributes dynamically .

Comment: i would like  to add my doubt here.whenever orientation changes from portrait to landscape xml is automatically fetched from layout-land folder.but when it changes from landscape to portrait it doesnt fetch the xml from layout folder

Comment: for that you need to setContentView() as per your condition .

Comment: i need to add the entire code inside the if else structure mentioned above?but xml name for landscape and portrait mode is same rite?

Comment: hi will you help me to achieve the wrapping effect for textview created dynamically.i have tried almost solution provided in stackoverflow site.but i found nothing is working out.will you suggest me a solution.